# Lubuntu 13.10 - two network icons

Tags: networking, lubuntu, 13.10, icons, lxde

I updated Lubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and now I have 2 network icons in the task bar
what do I have to do so it displays just one icon?

Comment: Having the same problem on Lubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, found another way:

go to `Start`(in linux I believe is called Menu ?!)->`Preferences`->`Desktop Session Settings`
uncheck `Network` from the list, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, then reboot
[image: how to]

Answer (score 1):

One way that survives a reboot is to go into `Menu, Preferences, Default applications for LXSession`. This is a new addition to Lubuntu 13.10 and apparently provides a GUI for adjusting certain settings. Unfortunately, I haven't come across documentation relating to it.

Anyway, I knew that I didn't have two network icons for the first day of running Lubuntu 13.10 but the two icons at startup came a day later.

I remembered tweaking a setting in `Default applications for LXSession`. Undoing that tweak, restores the single network icon in lxpanel on startup.

[image: LXSession settings]

In the `Autostart` tab, click on the box next to `Disable autostarted applications` and set it to `config-only`. The effect will be visible on reboot.

If you want certain applications of your own choice to autostart, you can use the GUI illustrated above: type or paste in the executable's command (and path). So something like `lxterminal` is enough but if I want a script of mine to run on startup, I'll enter `/home/vasa1/bin/cpu-usage-alert.sh`.

If you don't wish to use the GUI, you may edit `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` to look like, for example, this:

```
lxterminal
/home/vasa1/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
/home/vasa1/bin/cpu-usage-alert.sh
```

(It is recommended to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the last entry.)

Comment: ok, found another way:
Start(in linux I believe is called Menu ?!)->Preferences->Desktop Session Settings
uncheched **Network** from the list and rebooted, seems to work

Comment: @zmeul: then I suggest you to post your solution as an answer so that it will help others to get through their problem..

Comment: I have a hard time making the reply pretty - I fail ; the board code is unknown and quite strange to me

Answer (score 0):

**Well it's simple**

- Right click on the taskbar and select `Panel Settings`
- Go to <kbd>Panel Applets</kbd> tab
- You'll get a `System Tray` Icon. <kbd>Remove</kbd> it. <sub>Be sure which one you are removing by moving it up/down by using the buttons on the right</sub>. You can later add it by clicking <kbd>+Add</kbd> button there.
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the **Panel Preferences** window.

Thats it..:)

Comment: sorry, but this did not helped one bit

Comment: Have you actually tried this yourself in Lubuntu 13.10? Both `nm-applets` seem to be part of the same `System Tray`. I get rid of the second icon my finding out the other `nm-applet` process number and killing that one.

Comment: killing one nm-applet from the process list did work, but as soon as I reboot it's back to two icons

Comment: @zmeul, yes, that's why I didn't post the workaround as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

in "Default applications for LXSession" there is a section called "Network GUI", there is a drop-down list with "nm-applet" selected. click on that and set it to "no", hit "apply". log out and back in that's it. :)